# can't switch status value from 0 to 1 after calling function angular

Tags: rest, api, angular5

I am working on a frontend application with Angular 5 and using rest api from backend. Actually, I am developing admin platforme and I have two web pages, one for displaying list of customers and each one has list of feedbacks and one other get you to specific feedback details.

The feedback details display these properties: `account`, `feedback` itself and the `loyalty point` if existed.
There is two ways, if a feedback has its loyalty point then the feedback details will show details with loyalty point value else it will show empty input for this property and if the input is successful, it will return to main list with changed value of `status` of feedback from false to true.

I am using rest api and for this operation I successfully tested the API:

```js
API: PATCH /Feedbacks/:id
```

Here is my code:

**account.service.ts:**

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class AccountService {

      constructor(private http: Http) {}

      headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      options: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});

    // API: PATCH /Feedbacks/:id
      updateStatus(feedback: Feedback) {
        let url = "http://localhost:3000/api/Feedbacks";
        return this.http.patch(url + feedback.id, feedback, this.options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => {
          return Observable.throw(err)
        });
      }
    }
```

**component.html:**

```html
<form *ngIf="feedback">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputAccount">Account</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputAccount" value="{{feedback.account}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputFeedback">Feedback</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="InputFeedback" rows="3" placeholder="Feedback">{{feedback.feedback}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="InputLP">LP</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputLP" placeholder="LP" [(ngModel)]="account.lp" name="lp">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!edited; else showBack">
          <button (click)="addLP(account,feedback)" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="alert">Add LP</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts:**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.scss']
})
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {

  feedback = {};
  account = {};

  edited:boolean;
  status: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private accountService: AccountService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
          .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
            this.accountService.getFeedback(+params.get('idF')))
              .subscribe(feedback => this.feedback = feedback);

    this.route.paramMap
          .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
            this.accountService.getAccount(params.get('idC')))
              .subscribe(account => this.account = account);    
  }

  addLP(account:Account,feedback:Feedback){
    this.accountService.updateAccount(account)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.account = res as Account;
        console.log(res);
        if (account.lp == null){
          console.log(res);
          this.edited = false;
        } else {
          this.edited = true;
          this.accountService.updateStatus(feedback)
            .subscribe(res => { 
              feedback.status = true;
              this.feedback = res as Feedback;
              console.log(this.feedback);
            }, err => {
              console.log(err);
          });
        }
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

  back() {
    this.router.navigate(['list']);
  }

}
```

the feedback property:

```js
  public id?: number,
  public feedback?: string,
  public account?: string,
  public status?: boolean
```

Where the account is a foreign key to account table:

```js
  public account?: string,
  public lp?: string
```

When I try to switch status value automatically from false to true, the console log will return:

```
PATCH http://localhost:3000/api/Feedbacks2 404 (Not Found)
```

Any help would be appreciated! I really need to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code in **account.service.ts:**

```js
updateStatus(feedback: Feedback) {
    let url = "http://localhost:3000/api/Feedbacks";
    var body = {status: true};
    return this.http.patch(url +"/"+ feedback.id, body, this.options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => {
      return Observable.throw(err)
    });
  }
```

And it worked !